# Git history messed up by TFS PR

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration

I've been doing a PR from our main branch *dev* into a sub branch *dev_group1* that we use for parallel development and that we usually merge to *dev* and where me merge *dev* back from.

Dev has a No-Fast Forward merge policy in TFS (enforced), while dev_group1 has a Squash merge policy (enforced).

Every few weeks we do:

```
dev -> dev-group1
dev_group1 -> dev
```

This has been working fine for several months, but during the last merge we first did a

```
dev -> dev-group1
```

merge, which had about 20 file conflicts. We solved them and merged the PR.

When we tried to do the merge

```
dev_group1 -> dev
```

We saw pretty much the same files conflicting again (there were about 18 conflicts). This was already very strange, and we resolved to redo the merge

```
dev -> dev-group1
```

, which gave the same conflicts. We took the dev_group1 version, as it had the conflicts resolved.

When we went to TFS we saw that the PR was affecting about 180 tfs items, but without any file change.

We closed the PR.

Then we tried to redo the merge

```
dev_group1 -> dev
```

But we still have the same conflicts!

This is very puzzling, and I cannot provide an explanation for this. What can have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you use squash-merge merging dev to dev_group1 as well?

Comment: Yes, it’s the only one merge allowed by our policy

Comment: Hi MaPi, any update on this issue, did you get any chance to test the suggestion follow max630's laest comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to having a branch dev_group1 and another dev_GROUP1.

So, the second branch was created by mistake on a dev machine, and git treated them as separated branches, and in the TFS web interface they were shown as two separate ones.

But probably the TFS api was not discerning between the two. We deleted the dev_GROUP1 branch and everything was fine then.

Answer (score 2):

Squash merge discards ancestry connection with the source branch. So next time the metre is performed the merged changes are attempted to be merged again. It can succeed without conflict if changes on both sides are exactly the same. This can happen if changes in `dev_group1` and `dev` are unrelated. This is why your did not have conflict previous times. But once you have conflicts you will have them again and again.

You should not use squash merge when you intend to use the source branch after merge. As your `dev` branch is obviously to be used later, you should not squash merge from it.

Comment: If that were the case, It would have happened for all the other merges done in the past, right? We've been doing about 100 such merges and that never happened

Comment: I can only say from your words what you have there. Have you ever had conflicts before? Are you positive you did squash merges before? If you blame in `dev_group1` for changes not from group1, to you find the squash merge from `dev` or something else?